# Why TestNG priority feature is not running in their expected order

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I already have prioritized my test cases but they are not running in their priority order? Please refer the code below.

```
public class TestngFeature {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test(priority = 4, invocationCount = 5, alwaysRun = true, enabled = true)
    public void TestCaseOne() {
        System.out.println("TestCaseFirst -- This is First Test Case");
        System.out.println("TestCaseOne -- This is first Test Case");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, invocationTimeOut = 5, dependsOnMethods = "TestCaseOne")
    public void TestCaseSecond() {
        System.out.println("TestCaseSecond -- This is Second Test Case");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1, groups = { "Regression", "Smoke" }, dependsOnMethods = "TestCaseSecond")
    public void TestCaseThird() {
        System.out.println("TestCaseThird -- This is Third Test Case");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, groups = { "Regression", "Sanity" })
    public void TestCaseFourth() {
        System.out.println("TestCaseFourth -- This is Fourth Test Case");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = "Regression")
    public void TestCaseFifth() {
        System.out.println("TestCaseFifth -- This is Fifth Test Case");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3

TestCaseFourth -- This is Fourth Test Case

TestCaseFirst -- This is First Test Case

TestCaseOne -- This is first Test Case

TestCaseFirst -- This is First Test Case

TestCaseOne -- This is first Test Case

TestCaseFirst -- This is First Test Case

TestCaseOne -- This is first Test Case

TestCaseFirst -- This is First Test Case

TestCaseOne -- This is first Test Case

TestCaseFirst -- This is First Test Case

TestCaseOne -- This is first Test Case

TestCaseSecond -- This is Second Test Case

TestCaseThird -- This is Third Test Case

TestCaseFifth -- This is Fifth Test Case

PASSED: TestCaseFourth

PASSED: TestCaseOne

PASSED: TestCaseOne

PASSED: TestCaseOne

PASSED: TestCaseOne

PASSED: TestCaseOne

PASSED: TestCaseSecond

PASSED: TestCaseThird

PASSED: TestCaseFifth

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

This is what result I'm getting. Why is it not following the priority or otherwise how the priority works for TestNG?

Answer (score 3):

Because you defined `dependsOnMethods` for `TestCaseSecond` and `TestCaseThird`. It takes priority over `priority` attribute. From [testng Dependencies with annotations](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations)

> All the methods you depend on must have run and succeeded for you to run

`TestCaseFourth` has the highest priority (3) without dependency -> it runs first.

`TestCaseOne()` has the next highest priority (4) without dependency -> it runs second

`TestCaseSecond()` has the highest priority with all dependencies met (`TestCaseOne` ran) -> it runs third

`TestCaseThird()` has the highest priority with all dependencies met (`TestCaseSecond` ran) -> it runs fourth